# Nginx - rewrite root domain to point to specific Rails controller/action

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I have `http://foo.com` and `https://bar.com`.

When a visitor goes to `http://foo.com` I would like them to see the content on `https://bar.com/pages/about`

Both domains are hosted on the same server using nginx.

How can I do this with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect the entire server block like this - this is a redirect and not a re-write it will redirect any http or https to /bar.com/pages/about

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.com;
        return 301 $scheme://bar.com/pages/about;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect but instead serve the content from bar.com/pages/about to foo.com/. Its important I don't redirect for SEO purposes. In a way I'm looking for some sort of reverse proxy i guess.

Comment: nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: @pothi, that was it. If you make a response I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Pothi's comment the solution is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://bar.com/pages/about;
    }
}
```